# keyword search in sites

Tags: search, web

I am planning to build a small social networking site. What is the best way to support keyword search in the content. I am looking for an opinion considering the fact that the contents can grow few TBs in size.

thanks,
GL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html)/[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/features.html) to index contents resulting in efficient keyword search results and it is also very easy to implement a faceted search based on Solr if you have such a feature in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)?
It's a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks guys. Lucene, to my understanding will do the search inside the post contents. I am looking for keyword search where keyword need not necessarily be in the content itself. I looking for something that stackoverflow does ... searching based on keywords. I know I can use database - but are there any standard frameworks?